# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Chess Stack Exchange](http://chess.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Is this evaluation process and discussion only meant for comparing this site with other sites found on Google, or also discussing the quality of this site not in terms of other sites?

Comment: +1 @JiK: Agree, it's a bit unclear, thanks for asking! Here's what appears to be an example of the report that's generated by this [process](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/825/lets-get-critical-feb-2014-site-self-evaluation).

Comment: @Jik, please feel free to discuss the quality site in any absolute or relative way you'd like below. I know such has taken place during some of the previous site self-evaluations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How can black exploit this lead in development?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8193/how-can-black-exploit-this-lead-in-development)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can Black save this Knight vs Bishop endgame with a pawn down?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8220/can-black-save-this-knight-vs-bishop-endgame-with-a-pawn-down)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [FIDE rules regarding use of foreign languages in algebraic notation](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8156/fide-rules-regarding-use-of-foreign-languages-in-algebraic-notation)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Accidental moves in online chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/accidental-moves-in-online-chess)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Chess GUI with Time Handicap for Engine vs Engine matches](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8131/chess-gui-with-time-handicap-for-engine-vs-engine-matches)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How should an arbiter handle copying moves from another game?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8229/how-should-an-arbiter-handle-copying-moves-from-another-game)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [What are some good books on the Caro-Kann which propose a Black repertoire based on positional, strategic, solid, boring and quiet variations?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8161/what-are-some-good-books-on-the-caro-kann-which-propose-a-black-repertoire-based)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Guidelines for chess tournament prize distribution](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8163/guidelines-for-chess-tournament-prize-distribution)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [In a ChessBase opening tree how can we put a column that displays the percent of time each move is played or a column that displays "Perf" minus "Av"?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8215/in-a-chessbase-opening-tree-how-can-we-put-a-column-that-displays-the-percent-of)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [In the Classical Variation of the Caro-Kann, what is the most positional, strategic, quiet, slow, closed, boring, dry and solid variation for Black?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8102/in-the-classical-variation-of-the-caro-kann-what-is-the-most-positional-strate)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

Answer (score 4):

> We all love Chess Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people
>   out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that
>   this site exists.

http://chess-links.org/index500.html doesn't seem to know about us. Or are we just outside the top 500?

This is how chess-links describes itself -

> Top chess websites sorted by popularity (rating by alexa.com). Last
>   update 2015.02.19.  To suggest a new website that is not in the list
>   e-mail us at webchesslinks@gmail.com

Comment: I think the reason that chess-links.org doesn't list chess.stackexchange.com is because chess.stackexchange.com doesn't have an Alexa rank (since Alexa just considers it part of stackexchange.com).